# Markdown: Restoring a whitespace captured in delimiter

Tags: python, python-3.x, markdown

I'm creating a custom markdown extension in python who parse user input based on behind a `@` and at the end a white space `\s` (or end line). I don't have any problem to generate the correct HTML as follow:

**INPUT:** `@username`

**OUTPUT:** `<p><a href="/user/username">@Username</a></p>`

But this is correct if my tag doesn't have any other word after. If something comes after I generate a dirty HTML as:

**INPUT:** `@username as said something`

**OUTPUT:** `<p><a href="/user/username">@Username</a>as said something</p>`

As you can see, there is missing whitespace between the end of my tag `</a>` and the word `as`. I'm have trying many different things with `treepreprocessors` and `Postprocessor` but I don't have to make them work as I would.

The current full code is:

```py
from markdown.util import AtomicString, etree
from markdown.extensions import Extension
from markdown.inlinepatterns import InlineProcessor

USERNAME_RE = r'(@)(.*?)(\s|$)'

class UsernamePattern(InlineProcessor):
    """ Return a link to User page based on '/user/<username> """
    def handleMatch(self, m, data):
        username = m.group(2)

        el = markdown.util.etree.Element("a")
        el.set('href', f'/user/{username}')
        el.text = markdown.util.AtomicString(m.group(0))

        return el, m.start(0), m.end(0)


class UsernameExtension(Extension):
    """
    Wrap '@username' to <a href='/user/username'>@username</a>
    """
    def extendMarkdown(self, md, md_globals):
        md.registerExtension(self)
        md.inlinePatterns['usernamelink'] = UsernamePattern(USERNAME_RE, md)


def makeExtension(*args, **kwargs):
    return UsernameExtension(*args, **kwargs)
```

The greatest solution would be to add white space if a word follows the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `\s` is the issue.

A simple test code.

```
import re

r = r'(@)(.*?)(\s|$)'
print(re.sub(r, "LINKCODE", "@username as said something"))

t = r'(@)(\w*)'
print(re.sub(t, "LINKCODE", "@username as said something"))
```

output

```
LINKCODEas said something
LINKCODE as said something
```

So maybe you could try to replace your regex with `r'(@)(\w*)'` or `r'(@)([^\s]*)'`? Depending on what characters you're allowing in the username.

Comment: I think that I had spent too much time blocking on this space `(\s|$)` that I couldn't do without. Thank you so much for your response, I chose something really close to handle a character like `_` or `-` with pattern `'(@)(\S+)'` and is work great!

Answer (score 1):

This
`((?=@\w+ \w+)@\w+ |@\w+[^ ])`
 is the one that works for me.

You can check here it out [here](http://regexr.com/52e31) withe the examples bellow. 
There's a detailed explanation for every part. If it still needs some clarification, I'll gladly help you.

`@hello word
@hello $ymbol
@hello
newline
foo @hello word
foo @hello $ymbol
foo @hello
newline`

If there is a word after @xxx, it also matches a space.

Comment: Very interesting response. I hadn't actually thought about excluding the space with `[^ ]`, that a good idea. I don't know the positive lookahead `?=` that was interesting to learn about it, but I think it's not required to do it because markdown already applies patterns globally for me. Based on your answer, this pattern`(@)(\w+[^ ])` can the job perfectly!

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry about that, I got carried away by testing it online. Glad that I helped in some way!